# How to Make React awesome querybuilder show nested information

Tags: reactjs, frontend, query-builder, web-frontend

I am using react awesome query builder library

https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder

and there is a demo:

https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder

in the demo, there are nested fields: firstName and login under User

currently they are just displayed as firstName or login

How can I make them displayed as User.firstName or User.login in field ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example on Github, you can see it here. You need to pass the field as a struct.
https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/blob/master/examples/demo/config.tsx#L270

Here's the (minimal) documentation that mentions this:
[https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#features:~:text=structs%20(will%20be%20displayed%20in%20selectbox%20as%20tree)](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#features:%7E:text=structs%20(will%20be%20displayed%20in%20selectbox%20as%20tree))

Alternatively the syncfusion query builder has slightly better documentation (I'm in no way affiliated with them)

[https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/query-builder/data-binding/#:~:text=Complex%20Data%20Binding%20allows%20you%20to%20create%20subfield%20for%20columns.%20To%20implement%20complex%20data%20binding%2C%20either%20bind%20the%20complex%20data%20in%20nested%20columns%20or%20specify%20complex%20data%20source%20and%20separator%20must%20be%20given%20in%20querybuilder](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/query-builder/data-binding/#:%7E:text=Complex%20Data%20Binding%20allows%20you%20to%20create%20subfield%20for%20columns.%20To%20implement%20complex%20data%20binding%2C%20either%20bind%20the%20complex%20data%20in%20nested%20columns%20or%20specify%20complex%20data%20source%20and%20separator%20must%20be%20given%20in%20querybuilder).